# RavenDB Document Deleted Before Expiration

Tags: ravendb

I am attempting to write a document to RavenDB with an expiration 20 minutes in the future. I am not using the .NET client, just curl. My request looks like this:

```
PUT /databases/FRUPublic/docs/test/123 HTTP/1.1
Host: ravendev
Connection: close
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Raven-Entity-Name: tests
Raven-Expiration-Date: 2012-07-31T22:23:00
Content-Length: 14

{"data":"foo"}
```

In the studio I see my document saved with *Raven-Expiration-Date* set exactly 20 minutes from *Last-Modified*, however, within 5 minutes the document is deleted.
I see this same behavior (deleted in 5 minutes) if I increase the expiration date. If I set an expiration date in the past the document deletes immediately.

I am using build 960. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I specified the time to 10 millionth of a second and now documents are being deleted just as I would expect. 
For example:

> Raven-Expiration-Date: 2012-07-31T22:23:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

The date have to be in UTC, and it looks like you are sending local time.

Comment: I am using UTC time. Before I discovered that my documents were vanishing instantly (no ~5 minute delay).